# Streaming Analytics Query Yielding More Than Real Time Data

Tags: t-sql, azure, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

I recently set up a streaming analytics job pulling data from an event hub that's capturing about 1000 events per month. I'd like to pull real time data from the event hub and display near realtime data. I entered the following query that is downloading data successfully to the streaming analytics job:

```
    SELECT system.timestamp AS time
    , city
    , state
    , zip
    , hascontactedconsultant
    , websiteguideid
    , status
    , assignedto
    , type
    , COUNT(type)
INTO ttvleadsstream
FROM   ttvhuball
GROUP BY time
      , city
      , state
      , zip
      , hascontactedconsultant
      , websiteguideid
      , status
      , assignedto
      , type
      , TumblingWindow(ss, 5);
```

However, when I check on the dataset in my PowerBI online service, I'm noticing that the data is capturing and displaying events from now all the way back to yesterday. I'm not seeing what in my query is causing data to be preserved for longer than 5 seconds. Any ideas?

Comment: "I'm noticing that the data is capturing and displaying events from now all the way back to yesterday. I'm not seeing what in my query is causing data to be preserved for longer than 5 seconds." I'm confused. Is it showing a day worth of data or only 5 seconds in Power BI? Screenshot?

Comment: There's no issue to solve. Power BI is a *different* system. A Power BI dataset is handled by Power BI, even if it was created by Event Analytics. If you don't delete old data, or don't adjust your report's time scale, you'll see older data. In any case, Event Analytics doesn't handle output storeage, it only *sends* data to an output.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your query, if there are events, Azure stream analytics will output every 5 seconds.

Looks like you are sending the data to PowerBI. PowerBI deletes old data based on a retention policy. Details about the policy are here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt186545.aspx

Roughly, it will only purge old data when certain thresholds are met. This might be the reason why you see old data.